# AbstractGoogleClientRequest and GoogleClientRequestInitializer class not found in com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:2.0.0

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

My Android app with Cloud Endpoints says these classes do not exist

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;
```

when using any version higher than 1.31.0 of the following import

```
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.31.0'
```

The latest version is [2.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client-android) but even 1.32.1 has the issue. Anything that is 1.31.0 or lower works.

This is what my code looks like (taken from this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/8fb8f5be86234a5d9cf364da11079b4496c0c0ae/endpoints-frameworks/v2/app/src/main/java/com/example/migration/endpoints/app/MainActivity.java)):

```
    if (myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
        MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl("http://YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                });
        // end options for devappserver
        myApiService = builder.build();
    }

    try {
        return myApiService.sayHi(params[0]).execute().getData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

Is there a different way to be doing this in the new versions or is something else going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you shared and the code example you are following, it seems to be definitely an issue of the **API version**.

I highly recommend you to raise a new issue in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues).

As soon as you receive a response in the repository, I would advise you to keep working with a lower version for the time being.